# What are the list of files under Android Studio Project to add on GitHub Repository?

Tags: android

I am preparing my git profile and adding my projects on git. Want to know about the list of files and folders need to add on GitHub Repository. 
Using android Studio IDE.
It contains java, res, assets, manifests, Gradle Scripts.
What should we add on the GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

This is below .gitignore

```
/captures

# [Android] ========================
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
app/app-release.apk
/app/app-release.apk


# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log


## Directory-based project format:
.idea/

## File-based project format:
*.ipr
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml


# [Maven] ========================
target/
pom.xml.tag
pom.xml.releaseBackup
pom.xml.versionsBackup
pom.xml.next
release.properties


# [Gradle-Android] ========================

# Ignore Gradle GUI config
gradle-app.setting

# Gradle Signing
signing.properties
trestle.keystore

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
#*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*

# Misc
/.idea/workspace.xml
/captures
**/*.iml
*.class

# OS-specific files
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db


# Built application files
/*/build/
build/



# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Signing files
.signing/

# User-specific configurations
.idea/libraries/
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/.name
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
*.iml
```

Comment: I have added this in git ignore file. but in the source tree, it is still identifying the changes in the ignored files.

Comment: @gauravsngarg have you committed the gitignore file ? It may be cause of that